# IN operator is not working when using list as a input to teradata query in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el

I have a POC where I am taking data from teradata and updating it in salesforce. I am taking input from itemids which separated by comma like `'2345','456'`.

I'm first getting this value and setting it as payload. But in query we cannot use it directly. I've tried another solution of appending `''` to values and `','`. Hence payload becomes a string like `'2345','456'`. But when I'm passing this in query I'm getting 'bad parameter'. Anyone has any solution for it?

Comment: is the resulting query valid?  can you log and show it?

Comment: It might relates with the Query Type: Parameterized or Dynamic. You can try Dynamic for IN operator: `... IN (#[payload])`

Comment: I have tried it it's not working.

Comment: Luis: My query is valid i have checked it by hard coding the values.